# Node.js WebSocket just sends blobs

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm trying to add WebSocket connections to my website, so I started out with a basic code to send and receive a string. It was working like it should yesterday, and even after rewritting it exactly the same way, all I get is [object Blob] instead of my string, I've searched for hours now with no success. Here's the code:

Server:

```
import WebSocket, {WebSocketServer} from 'ws';
const server = new WebSocketServer({port:'8080'});

server.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('message', message => {
        socket.send(message);
    });
});
```

Client:

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
var text = document.getElementById("text");

socket.onopen = ({e}) => {
    console.log("Conectado");
}

socket.onmessage = ({data}) => {
    console.log('Mensagem do servidor! ' + data);
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
    socket.send('Oi');
}

function updateText(){
    text = document.getElementById("text");
    socket.send(text.value);
}
```

Comment: I have. The point here is that I never created a blob, and it wasn't a blob the last time I wrote that code. The search doesn't solve my problem. Or does it actually need to be a blob for every string I send using WebSocket?

Answer (score 1):

After some more hours tinkering with the code, it seems like it was some weird variable type stuff. Only worked when I sent a hardcoded string with the message, so I tried .toString() and it worked like it should, just wasn't reading the message as a string.